# Problem Accessing Content Manager after Upgrading SDL Tridion Sites 9.1 to 9.5

Tags: content-manager, upgrade, sites-9.5

I am trying to upgrade Sites 9.1 to 9.5 in an AWS instance and, as part of that, I have done the following:

- Installed the Add-on Service and I can hit the Adds-on URL.

[image]

- Installed the Access Management Service as an IIS website and created a windows identity provider. I am able to hit the Access Management URL.

[image]

- Enabled integration with the Add-ons Service and Access Management Service during the Content Manager installation and the installation completed successfully.

When I try accessing the Content Manager UI, I get the following error:

> ```
> Cannot open database "Tridion_cm" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\EC2AMAZ-TUJ3HK0$'.
> ```

I tried granting access to the Trdion_cm database for WORKGROUP\EC2AMAZ-TUJ3HK0$ user, but there is no such user.

What am I missing with this? Do we need to grant access to any other user on the Tridion_cm database?

Comment: Looks like you are using integrated authentication for cm database. Did you try following steps from following page
https://docs.sdl.com/816112/673783/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/configuring-the-content-manager-database-for-integrated-authentication

Comment: @StefanKlasnic - Thanks for your reply! No, I am using Windows authentication though, which was working fine with 9.1.

Comment: @Sabarish Senthilnathan , 
Just to understand , when you did the upgrade from 9.1 to 9.5 , did you use the AdministratorUserName and AdministratorUserPassword and not the Existing database users example TCMDBUser , if so What do you see on the Tridion Snap in for the DB settings and you had mentioned you did not use IntegratedSecurity

Comment: Go to the SDL Console database section to see first what is the username is provided in the installation. if needed you can decrypt the TridionContentManager.config file double-checks the connection string that was provided.

Comment: Any updates on this @SabarishSenthilnathan did you try the options mentioned or you still facing the issue let us know

Comment: Got this to work by granting access to the `tridion_cm` database for the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE user. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error message is confusing. Access to the tridion_cm database is failing, and *because of that*, the login for your User (WORKGROUP\EC2AMAZ-TUJ3HK0$) fails. This does not mean that the database connection makes use of your user's credentials, at least I hope not.

You should check the database credentials configured for the content manager. This should have nothing to do with the Access Management feature, which is used for User logins, and not for a service account such as is used for the database.